# How to rollback the changes in Liquibase in springboot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I have configured liquibase in my springboot application. I would like to test the rollback in liquibase.

```
<changeSet id="rollbackTest" author="test_user">
    <createTable tableName="multiRollback1">
        <column name="id" type="int"/>
    </createTable>
    <rollback>
        drop table multiRollback1;
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

How do i force my application to invoke rollback? I do not want to add another changeset for that as that would not be a real rollback test.

Also, we do not use maven plugin. These configurations are being executed as part of spring boot application startup.

I am trying hard to simulate this, I want to see my application executing rollback tag.

Comment: `I do not want to add another changeset for that as that would not be a real rollback test.`  - why?  You can copy this changeset (only change the `id`) and execute it. Since there's no preConditions, this changeset will fail, and I suppose the table will be dropped.  Also, liquibase has a built-in `rollback` for such simple changesets.

Comment: I tried that, first change set creates the table and second change set fails without executing rollback. 
    <changeSet id="rollback1002-1" author="test_user">
  <createTable tableName="rollback1002">
   <column name="id" type="int"/>
  </createTable>
 </changeSet>

 <changeSet id="rollback1002-2" author="test_user">
  <createTable tableName="rollback1002">
   <column name="id" type="int"/>
  </createTable>
  <rollback>
   drop table rollback1002;
  </rollback>
 </changeSet>